# How do I load the dump.rdb file into redis?

Tags: linux, unix, redis

I have a dump.rdb file, which is in the same directory as redis.config.

When I start my sever:

```
redis-server ./redis.config
```

It does not load the data in that 1 GB file.

How do I load that data?

Answer (score 9):

Edit your config file to set the `dir` option to the current working directory:

```
# The filename where to dump the DB
dbfilename dump.rdb

# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
# 
# Also the Append Only File will be created inside this directory.
# 
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
dir /current/working/directory
```

Comment: It's important to also turn off Append Only mode: `appendonly no` - otherwise nothing happens. (as per other answers here)

Comment: See also duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497234/how-to-recover-redis-data-from-snapshotrdb-file-copied-from-another-machine

Answer (score 3):

Do as follow:

1. modify the redis.conf, disable the appendonly.aof

```
    appendonly no
```

2. Restart the redis-server
3. Run `redis-cli BGREWRITEAOF`, to create a new appendonly file.
4. Modify redis config `appendonly` to `yes` and restart your redis-server

Please see [this](http://zdk.github.io/redis-backup-and-restore/)

Answer (score 1):

We found we had to switch aof off beforehand otherwise redis creates a blank aof at boot and uses that instead of the rdb file. Once redis creates a populated aof then you can switch aof back on.